# ng-click ng-keypress passing form data not working

Tags: angularjs, keypress, angularjs-ng-click

Im trying to send data from user input to display on the screen when button click.
The problem is that if i click on the button it simply passes to the next value without gathering the information and displaying in the screen. If i press ENTER it works how it should. i have searched all over internet several examples but simply couldnt get it to work. im using at the moment :

```
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default next bt_submits" type="button" ng-click="addData(newData)">
            &nbsp;<span class="bt_arrow"></span>
    </button>
```

full html:

```
<div class="boxContent col-md-12">
        <h1>{{lang.sec101.h1}}</h1>
        <div class="col-md-12 lineBorder noPad" >
            <div class="box1">
                <p>
                    {{lang.sec101.title}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- dynamic form -->
            <div class="col-md-12 borderBox boxLeft bg_box">
                <form novalidate name="addForm">
                    <div class="boxLeft" ng-show="Question != ''">
                        <div ng-show="Question.infotip != 'yes'">
                            <h1 class="heading_left">{{Question.ask}}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-show="Question.infotip == 'yes'">
                            <h1 class="heading_left info">{{Question.ask}}
                                <span class="infotip yourData" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip-trigger="click" tooltip="{{Question.infotipText}}"></span>
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxRight" ng-show="Question != ''">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-default next bt_submits" type="button" ng-click="addData(newData)">
                            &nbsp;<span class="bt_arrow"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="boxRejestracjaInput">
                        <!-- <div id="legg-select" ng-if="Question.type === 'select'">
                            <select ng-options="opt.val for opt in Question.options" name="{{Question.name}}" ng-model="value" ng-keypress="enter($event,value.val)"></select>
                        </div> -->
                        <div class="newSelect">
                            <label ng-if="Question.type === 'select'">
                                <select ng-options="opt.val for opt in Question.options" name="{{Question.name}}" ng-model="value" ng-keypress="enter($event,value.val)"></select>
                            </label>
                        </div>



                        <input
                            ng-if="Question.type === 'text'"
                            type="{{Question.type}}"
                            name="institutionName"
                            class="inputName"
                            value="{{Question.value}}"
                            ng-model="value"
                            ng-minlength="{{Question.min}}"
                            ng-maxlength="{{Question.max}}"
                            ng-keypress="enter($event,value)"
                            placeholder="{{Question.placeholder}}"
                            ng-pattern="{{Question.pattern}}" />
                            <!-- <div class="custom-error institution" ng-show="addForm.institutionName.$error.minlength || addForm.institutionName.$error.maxlength">
                                Minimum {{Question.min}} znaków
                            </div> -->
                            <!-- <div class="custom-error institution" ng-show="addForm.institutionName.$error.maxlength">
                                   Max {{Question.max}} znaków
                            </div> -->
                            <div class="custom-error institution" ng-show="addForm.institutionName.$error.pattern || addForm.institutionName.$error.maxlength || addForm.institutionName.$error.minlength">
                                   {{Question.copy}}
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <p>
                {{lang.sec101.title2}}
            </p>
            <a href="rejestracja_10edit.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-default bt_edit" type="button">
                {{lang.sec101.title3}}<span class="btn_bg_img"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 noPad" ng-repeat="sek in formOut">
            <h3 class="daneHeading">{{sek.name}}</h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" >
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 boxContent3 boxes" ng-repeat="row in sek.data">
                        <span class="leftBoxContrnt">{{row.shortAsk}}</h4></span>
                        <h4 class="rightBoxContrnt">{{row.value}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="row col-md-12" >
            <h3 class="daneHeading">Hasło</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 " >
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 boxContent3">
                    <span class="leftBoxContrnt">Test</h4></span><span class="blueTxt">&nbsp;*</span>
                    <h4 class="rightBoxContrnt">Test</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> -->
</div>
```

my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize', 'nya.bootstrap.select', 'jackrabbitsgroup.angular-slider-directive']);

// var rej10_Controller = function($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $timeout, limitToFilter) {
app.controller('rej10_Controller', ['$scope', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$sce', '$timeout', 'limitToFilter',
    function($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $sce, $timeout, limitToFilter) {

        var view = 10,
            arr,
            data,
            counterSection = 0,
            counterAsk = 0;

        $scope.opts = {};
        $scope.slider_id = 'my-slider';
        $scope.opts = {
            'num_handles': 1,
            'user_values': [0, 1],
            'slider_min': 0,
            'slider_max': 1,
            'precision': 0,
        };

        /* language */
        if (!$cookieStore.get('lang'))
            $cookieStore.put('lang', 'pl');


        var lang = $cookieStore.get('lang');
        $scope.language = lang;

        $scope.setLang = function(data) {
            $cookieStore.put('lang', data);

            $http.get('../widoki/json/lang/' + data + '/rej_' + view + '.json').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.lang = data;
                $scope.Question = $scope.lang.formIn.sekcja[counterSection].data[counterAsk];
                console.log($scope.lang);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('error load json');
            });

            $scope.language = data;
        };
        /* get language pack */
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '../widoki/json/lang/' + lang + '/rej_' + view + '.json'
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.lang = data;
            $scope.Question = $scope.lang.formIn[counterSection].data[counterAsk];
            $scope.langLen = $scope.lang.formIn.length;

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('error load json');
        });

        /* dynamic form */

        $scope.enter = function(ev, d) {
            if (ev.which == 13) {
                $scope.addData(d);
            }
        };
        $scope.addData = function(data) {
            var newData = {};
            /* latamy po id sekcji i po id pytania */
            if (!$scope.formOut) {
                $scope.formOut = [];
            }


            /* budowanie modelu danych wychodzcych */
            newData = {
                sekcja: counterSection,
                name: $scope.lang.formIn[counterSection].name,
                data: []
            };
                console.log(name);
            if (!$scope.formOut[counterSection]) {
                $scope.formOut.push(newData);
            }
            $scope.formOut[counterSection].data.push($scope.Question);
            $scope.formOut[counterSection].data[counterAsk].value = data;

            counterAsk++;

            // zmieniamy sekcje
            if (counterAsk == $scope.lang.formIn[counterSection].data.length) {
                counterAsk = 0;
                counterSection++;
            }
            if (counterSection == $scope.lang.formIn.length) {
                $scope.Question = '';
                /* zrobic ukrycie pola z formularza */
            } else {
                $scope.Question = $scope.lang.formIn[counterSection].data[counterAsk];
            }

            /* konwertowanie do jsona */
            //var Json = angular.toJson($scope.formOut);
            //console.log(Json);
        };
        $scope.submit = function() {
            alert('form sent'); /* wysĹanie formularza */
        };
        $scope.getClass = function(b) {
            return b.toString();
        };

    }
]);
app.directive('ngEnter', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
app.config(['$tooltipProvider',
    function($tooltipProvider) {
        $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({
            'mouseenter': 'mouseleave',
            'click': 'click',
            'focus': 'blur',
            'never': 'mouseleave',
            'show': 'hide'
        });
    }
]);
var ValidSubmit = ['$parse',
    function($parse) {
        return {
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                return {
                    post: function postLink(scope, element, iAttrs, controller) {
                        var form = element.controller('form');
                        form.$submitted = false;
                        var fn = $parse(iAttrs.validSubmit);
                        element.on('submit', function(event) {
                            scope.$apply(function() {
                                element.addClass('ng-submitted');
                                form.$submitted = true;
                                if (form.$valid) {
                                    fn(scope, {
                                        $event: event
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        scope.$watch(function() {
                            return form.$valid
                        }, function(isValid) {
                            if (form.$submitted == false)
                                return;
                            if (isValid) {
                                element.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
                            } else {
                                element.removeClass('has-success');
                                element.addClass('has-error');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
];
app.directive('validSubmit', ValidSubmit);
```

I cant figure out what is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your ngClick button handler to an ngSubmit form handler and wiring that up. You didn't say what browser you're using, but most of them auto-submit forms on an ENTER keypress unless you trap it (which you aren't). Clicking a button won't do this.